# Rails: if model attribute is true, then do following in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a RoR application and I have solved my problem in a way but I think it is not the best way to make it work. I have an attribute on my ***ListItems*** model which is called ***ticked***, and I want to write a label on my view (html.erb) regarding whether the ticked attribute of my model is **true** or **false**, so far I have this:

```
<%= label_tag '', "Finished" if list_item.ticked? %>
<%= label_tag '', "Not finished" if !list_item.ticked? %></p>
```

where **list_item** is one of my models, and **list_items.ticked?** gives either false or true. I wonder if i could write something like this:

```
<%= if list_item.ticked? ? 'Finished' : 'Not Finished' %>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you could just use the ternary operator directly instead of using an `if`. Something like:

```
<%= label_tag '', list_item.ticked? ? 'Finished' : 'Not Finished' %>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote/accept as you see fit (and for future searchers).